# Auto complete as you type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was looking the w3cschool link for auto complete as you type.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

The above only works for the first ordering for names eg. If country name is United States. You need to type Uni and it shows in drop-down. How to make it work if you type any letter eg ted or state so it still shows. United States in drop down.

Comment: Take a look at [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is do a `includes` string comparison instead of `starts With` and you should be all set if you just show the matching country instead f substring of matching text.

```
if (arr[i].toUpperCase().includes(val.toUpperCase())) {
  /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  /*make the matching letters bold:*/
  b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i] + "</strong>";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9ym4Lcta/1/

Answer (score 1):

In step 4 change this line:

```
    if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase())
```

To:

```
    if (arr[i].toUpperCase().includes(val.toUpperCase()))
```

Comment: except without substr()